# Probability of getting a number in a sudoku box when two numbers are already fixed.

Tags: probability

Imagine a sudoku box, I named the rows by alphabets like $a,b,c,d...$ And the columns as $1,2,3,4...$ If two numbers were already filled,i,e at $(a,1)$ there is '$1$' and at $(b,2)$ there is '$2$' which are fixed. The question is, what is the probability of getting the number '$3$' at the box $(c,4)$.

Comment: do you mean (c,3) ?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that there is a $1$ at $(a,1)$ and a $2$ at $(b,2)$ doesn't affect the chances of any other number to be at $(c,4)$. So, the probability will be $1\over 9$ 
 However, it will be different if you were asking about $(c,3)$ . Then, you can't have $1$ or $2$ there and so, the probability of $3$ will be $1\over 7$.